# ArcGIS JS - Printing with private layers

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, printing

I have a map built using ArcGIS JS API v4.8. The map has a basemap and FeatureLayer that are both secured by a custom API and a server-side proxy.

I'm looking to make use of the Printing widget, but if I have the private FeatureLayer displayed, it fails to work, and if I switch that layer off it provides a print out but it doesn't show the custom basemap (so it's effectively just a blank page).

Is there a way to use the Printing widget even if layers/basemaps are not publically accessible? I presume the issue here is the PrintTaskUrl that's hosted by Esri can't access my private layers? Does anyone have any suggested workarounds for this at all?

Comment: Are you using the built-in IdentityManager (https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-identity-IdentityManager.html) to authenticate access to your secured layer?

Comment: We're not, no - it's a custom authentication layer powered by Azure API Manager. One layer is stored in AGOL but the other is hosted internally.

Answer (score 1):

To print secure layers, the preferred way is probably to have your own print service, and embed the authentication in it.

See https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/create-web-apps/windows/printing-maps-that-contain-secured-services.htm for more info.